# .groupby().to_latex() output broken

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I'm trying to export `pandas.DataFrame.describe()` to `LaTex` using the `to_latex()`-method. This works all fine as long as I don't apply the `groupby()`-method beforehand. With a grouped DataFrame, the first row has no values, even though its label is `count`. Note that the first row of a grouped dataframe is used to mark down the variable used for grouping in iPython notebook.

I'm using pandas 0.16.2, python 3.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Now also posted as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10660).

Here some examples:

Without `groupby`:

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &    IS\_FEMALE \\
\midrule
count &  2267.000000 \\
mean  &     0.384649 \\
...
...
75\%   &     1.000000 \\
max   &     1.000000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

With `groupby`:

```
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule
  &       &    IS\_FEMALE \\
\midrule
0 & count &              \\     % <-- note missing value here
  & mean &  1134.000000 \\
  & std &     0.554674 \\
...
...
  & 75\% &     0.000000 \\
  & max &     0.000000 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Output in the notebook:

[image]

Comment: Could you post an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) as SO is not really the appropriate place to post bugs unless you're doing something wrong, the pandas devs usually respond quickly on Github and sometimes on SO too

Comment: I'll be happily posting this on Github, but to be honest, I wanted to clarify if it was my bad, first.

Comment: Keep it here for now but please post it as an issue it'll be looked at quicker by the devs

Comment: [Done.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10660)